# Order SparseVectors by the closest distance to given SparseVector

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark dataset containing a column of SparseVector types. Additionally, I have another SparseVector $X$ which is not a part of the dataset. I want to order my dataset according to the closest distance (or similarity) relative to $X$.
Can anyone help me with how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears that problem was solved with [BucketedRandomProjectionLSH](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/ml/feature/BucketedRandomProjectionLSH.html). After **fit** && **transformation**, and **approxNearestNeighbors** resulted dataset contains distCol, which (as per [LSH.scala](https://fossies.org/linux/spark/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/LSH.scala)):

> @param distCol Output column for storing the distance between each result row and the key.